# Что значат знаки ^,~ в зависимостях?

Tags: зависимости

Что значат знаки ^,~ в зависимостях?

Comment: в каких зависимостях?

Comment: Во всяких там нугетах и т п.

Comment: в зависимости от конкретной программы может значить что угодно

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно это поможет:

Семантическое Версионирование

В npm может использоваться (~) и (^) для указания версий зависимостей.

Если Вы видите **~1.0.2** это значит что подходит версия **от 1.0.2 включительно** до **1.1.0 не включая её**, то есть максимально доступная **патч** версия после версии **1.0.2**.

Если Вы видите **^1.0.2** это значит что подходит версия **от 1.0.2 включительно** до версии **2.0.0 не включая её**, т.е. максимальная **минорная+патч** версия после версии **1.0.2**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почерпнуто отсюда:

[Семантическое Версионирование 2.0.0](https://semver.org/lang/ru/)

[Нумерация версий программного обеспечения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

[npm-semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver)